# Graphviz Dot failing to remove overlaps due to missing library

Tags: command-line, homebrew, graphviz, dot

I am trying to run the following dot command from the command line:

```
dot -v ~/Documents/FlowGraph/dot_sample_1_full.dot -Tpng 'Documents/FlowGraph/sampleOutput.png' -Ksfdp -Goverlap=false
```

but it is failing with this output:

```
dot - graphviz version 2.36.0 (20140111.2315)
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
libdir = "/usr/local/lib/graphviz"
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_neato_layout.6.dylib
Using layout: sfdp:neato_layout
The plugin configuration file:
    /usr/local/lib/graphviz/config6
        was successfully loaded.
    render  :  cairo dot fig map pic pov ps quartz svg tk vml xdot
    layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device  :  bmp canon cgimage cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps exr fig gif gv icns ico imap imap_np ismap jp2 jpe jpeg jpg pct pdf pic pict plain plain-ext png pov ps ps2 psd sgi svg svgz tga tif tiff tk vml vmlz x11 xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4 xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) bmp eps gif jpe jpeg jpg pdf png ps svg
fontname: "Times-Roman" resolved to: (ps:pango  Times,  REGULAR) (PangoCairoCoreTextFont) "Times" 
  margin 8
pack info:
  mode   node
  size   0
  flags  0
ctrl->overlap=-1
Error: remove_overlap: Graphviz not built with triangulation library
```

I've Googled and found [this thread](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php#comment-436), which suggested:

> gts has to be installed before graphivz so enter 'sudo brew remove
>   graphviz' to remove graphivz and 'sudo brew install gts' and 'sudo
>   install graphivz' to install graphivz with gts.

but that didn't seem to work. I'm still getting the error so either I didn't do it right, or that wasn't the solution for me.

**How do I add the triangulation library to graphviz?**

Comment: Ubuntu/Linux users, check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42579735/993683).

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem on macOS with sfdp and the following is what solved it.

```
$ brew uninstall graphviz  
$ brew install gts 
$ brew install --with-gts graphviz
```

Comment: Saved my bacon. I was spending hours trying to figure out why all my edges were criss-crossing.

Answer (score 4):

Homebrew doesn't support command line install options anymore, so the previous answers will not work anymore.

However, by accident i discovered that removing graphviz, installing gts, then installing graphviz works. It seems that graphviz will use gts if it isnt installed, but for some reason, it isnt a dependency.

`brew remove graphviz 
brew install gts
brew install graphviz`