# Ubuntu graphviz 'sfdp' not working

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, package, updates, graphviz

I'm trying to make some  *Networkx Graphviz* graphs.

After running: `pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G, prog = 'sfdp')`. An error occured, saying:

```
Error: remove_overlap: Graphviz not built with triangulation library
```

After some *Google* research I found that GTS is the problem. [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/graphviz/+bug/1409280) stated:

> The Graphviz package is built --without-gts. This is bad news for sfdp, which complains “Error: remove_overlap: Graphviz not built with triangulation library” and fails to produce the beautiful output it creates when compiled --with-gts

Looking at comments ( on bug report ), someone said that the upstream sources for *Graphviz* are kept at [link](https://github.com/ellson/graphviz) but I couldn't find new versions to download.

On package [list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/graphviz) I have the latest one (2.36 for *trusty*).

Anyone else having problems with `sfdp`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same problem, no solution yet.

Comment: @PaulSmith I gave up a long time ago :D

Answer (score 7):

For the ubuntu users, this is how I got grapvhiz to work on 16.04,compiling graphviz-2.40.1 from source:

In a first step , [GTS](http://gts.sourceforge.net/) needs to be installed , as  graphviz looks for the [gts.pc file](http://www.graphviz.org/content/unable-use-prism).

Running

`apt-file search gts.pc`

Informs me I have to install 'libgts-dev' :

```
sudo apt install libgts-dev
```

next make pkg-config aware of the files:

```
pkg-config --libs gts

pkg-config --cflags gts
```

run configure to link in the gts library:

```
./configure --with-gts  --prefix ~
make
make install
```

SFDP no longer throws the error 'Error: remove_overlap: Graphviz not built with triangulation library'

The command line codes for the pkg config I modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320267/package-opencv-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path) answer.

Comment: Downloaded `graphviz-2.40.1.tar.gz` from [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_source.php) and ran through your procedure, and it works - sort of. I can use some commands (`dot`, `fdp`), but not others (`sfdp`, `neato`). Any idea what's going on here? (Using Ubuntu 16.04.2)
`

Comment: `/usr/bin/sfdp: No such file or directory` is the problem, btw. Whereas the other commands work just like normal. [This post](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=853468) seems to agree with the above procedure answer (1. install `libgts-dev`, 2. add `--with-gts` to configuration). Anyone else out there having the same problem as me?

Comment: Okay, I got it working (no problems yet, at least) - for others who have similar troubles, I wrote some info here: https://github.com/ellson/graphviz/issues/1237 Though it was probably just something I did wrong. Thanks, Sam!

Comment: Hi @JoeRocc , sorry I did not see your comment. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is for Ubuntu, but in case someone is having the same problem on *macOS* using *homebrew* the following worked for me:

```
brew reinstall graphviz --with-gts
```

Comment: As of now, gts is one of the dependencies of graphviz, so simple reinstalling solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I *might* have it working for Ubuntu 14.04, YMMV

Download the following graphviz packages directly from https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=graphviz

- graphviz_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb
- libcgraph6_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb
- libgvc6_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb
- libgvpr2_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb
- libltdl7_2.4.6-0.1_amd64.deb
- python-pygraphviz_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb

I used version 2.38.0-13 from the stretch(testing) group.
You will need to remove the 32bit libltdl7 if present:

```
sudo apt-get remove libltdl7:i386
```

Install the packages directly with

```
sudo dpkg -i graphviz_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb    
sudo dpkg -i libcgraph6_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb libgvc6_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb libgvpr2_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb libltdl7_2.4.6-0.1_amd64.deb
```

You can expect dependency errors. I cleared them with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And then re-install

```
sudo dpkg -i graphviz_2.38.0-13_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i python-pygraphviz_1.3.1-1_amd64.deb
```

The error no longer appeares though I would be hard pushed to say the graphs are any better.